# Vertical or horizontal t-sql table for multiple settings?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's assume that you need a table to store settings.  For example, I want to store vehicle settings in a table, but there are over 100 settings, so is is better to have a table with 100 columns or a table with maybe 2 columns (1 for the name of the setting and 1 for the value of the setting)?

Comment: Are all the settings the same data type?  Will they always be?

Comment: They are not all the same data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either have its advantage and disadvantage.

For flexibility, I would go for Vertical (each setting in each row) approach

If you are using one setting per row,

- it will be easier to add new settings or remove unwanted setting in the future without changing the table schema.
- You can have an user interface to do this without touching the database
- Your clients can add/remove settings without requesting your attention

BUT(s)

- You may need to remember the setting keyword, no intellisense
- Looping, Cursor

The 100 columns approach

- Intellisense
- It's just one record, should be faster
- No looping, no cursor

BUT(s)

- You may have to fill all columns if they are not NULLable
- Change schema, you may have to change all dependent codes

Answer (score 1):

I'm all for normalization. So I would create Three tables: Vehicle, Setting and VehicleSetting that will have three columns for vehicle id, setting id and Setting value. Actually I do have this implementation in production. My settings table also has Default Value that is stored if user doesn't specify the value explicitly.

This approach is very convenient if you decide to add a setting in the future. Instead of modifying the table and potentially facing refactoring, you would just add another record to settings table and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

I don't disagree with the answer from Dimitri but present the other side.

12 or 100 look at how often to you expect the settings to change.

If each setting is a column then you have a program change for a new property. More simple query syntax.  If they are singe value properties then I would argue you still have 3rd normal form and more efficient queries.

If you go with 3 tables as Dimitri suggested then you have a slightly more complex design but you have that ability to add and revise properties run time.  The query will be more complex with several joins.  You could build a query on the setting table to build your real query.  For sure I would use joins over cursor suggested by tcoder.

If you have a .NET or other front end then you could also build up the query by reading from the settings table.  If you are binding to like a GridView you will not be able to generate columns but again not that much work.